# UIBarButtonItem appearance setBackgroundImage black line under buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uiappearance

I have a little black line under all of my buttons which are in `UIControlStateNormal`. Back buttons and Done buttons are not affected.

Here is image:

[image]

You can clearly see it, and it's super annoying. Here is how I'm setting all of my images:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I'm using the same technique for back and done buttons, which doesn't have issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:...]`. Seems like your image is getting tiled because it's shorter than the button height.

Comment: Yeah, it on all images. What sizes do you recommend using for buttons?

Comment: UIBarButtonItems are 30pt high. If you want a custom height you have to use UIButton as a customView.

Comment: I was going through the same problem which i resolved by using UIButton instead of UIBarButton [similar to what @TatarasanuVictor has mentioned below]. But now I know another method given by erurainon which I am gonna try

Answer (score 2):

Might not be exactly what you want but this is how i handle this :

```
+ (id) customButtonWithImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName selectedImageNamed:(NSString *)selectedImageName leftCapWidth:(CGFloat)leftCapWidth edgeInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)edgeInsets title:(NSString *)title target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {

    UIButton* customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [customButton addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    customButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    customButton.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.25f];
    customButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, -1.0f);
    customButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    customButton.titleEdgeInsets = edgeInsets;
    UIImage* navButtonBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:0.0f];
    UIImage* navButtonPressedBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:selectedImageName] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:0.0f];
    [customButton setBackgroundImage:navButtonBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customButton setBackgroundImage:navButtonPressedBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [customButton setBackgroundImage:navButtonPressedBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(30.0f, 30.0f);
    if (title != nil) {
        size = [[NSString stringWithString:title] sizeWithFont:customButton.titleLabel.font];
    }
    customButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width + 20.0f, 30.0f);
    customButton.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    customButton.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    return [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton] autorelease];
}
```

I have a static method that returns a nice button for me  :)

ANd

```
+ (id) customBarButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector {
    return [self customButtonWithImageNamed:@"navbarbutton"
                         selectedImageNamed:@"navbarbutton_active"
                               leftCapWidth:5.0f
                                 edgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f)
                                      title:title
                                     target:target
                                   selector:selector];
}
```

=> 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem customBarButtonWithTitle:@"Info" target:self selector:@selector(pushInfoViewController)];